# Instead of selecting a column to sort a table by in a dropdown, how do I add the sorting column names in a separate column?

Tags: sorting, filter, tableau-api, dashboard, columnsorting

I have a workbook where I have displayed a table where the user can view the top 3 IDs based on a column they can select from a dropdown (Measure A, Measure B, ... , Measure H):

[image]

Now, instead of this, I want to add a separate column called Sorting Criterion to the table that would store the column names with which the respective rows of the table was sorted. So, the expected output is something like this:

[image]

How do I do this? I'm open to using Tableau Prep Builder, if needed, for intermediate steps that may be too convoluted for Tableau Desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Create a calculated field that just contains the Sort By parameter. Add this calculated field to your view.

[image]